# How to take location in one array to find a element of that location in another array?

Tags: python

I am trying to get a return value from an array but keep getting an error. The code is below and the error is posted below the code

```
proxAtime = array ('d',[])
proxAV = array ('d',[])

proxBtime = array ('d',[])
proxBV = array ('d',[])

time_average = array('d',[])

# while sample used to loop program (Time set below at end of indentation minus sample)
sample=10000
while sample >= 0:
# Chip A below rounding to two digits (format)/ logging out/ then print function.

    now = datetime.now() # current date and time
    time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    A0VOLTS = format((A0.value / 5322.926829268293), ".2f")
    Samplelogger.info("  Prox Switch A SAMPLE Voltage   A0: " + A0VOLTS + "V")
    print("  Prox Switch A SAMPLE  Voltage A0: " + A0VOLTS +"V",time)
    shellA0 = ("A0") + (A0VOLTS) + (time)
   
    strip = re.findall((r"[AB][0-9]([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})"),shellA0)
    strip2 = re.findall((r"[AB][0-9]([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})"),shellA0)
    
    volt1 = strip.pop (0)[0] # Seperating Volts and Time
    time1 = strip2.pop (0)[1] #Seperating Volts and Time
    print (volt1)
    print (time1)
    time1 = (time1)  
    t = time1 # To convert the time1 in to seconds
    (h, m, s) = t.split(':')
    time1_seconds =  + int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)
    print (time1_seconds)
    proxAtime.append (time1_seconds)#Putting Time in to Array in seconds
    len(proxAtime)#Counting the elements of the time array
    if len(proxAtime) < 100 :
        print (proxAtime)
    print ("  Number of time elements in proxA Array",len(proxAtime))
    volt1 = float (volt1)
    proxAV.append (volt1)# Putting Volts in to Array
    len(proxAV)#Counting the elements of the voltage array
    if len(proxAV) < 100 :
        print (proxAV)
    print ("  Number of voltage elements in proxA Array",len(proxAV))
    
    print (proxAV)
    result=[i for i, e in enumerate (proxAV) if e == 1.91]#Accessing element in voltage array location based on set value 1.91.
    print (result)
    
    result2 = resultpop.[0]
    print (result2)
```

Error below

```
 %Run 'MCP 1.23 2021.py'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pi/Desktop/MCP 1.23 2021.py", line 131
        result2 = resultpop.[0]
                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Well obviously `resultpop.[0]` is invalid syntax. Did you mean `resultpop[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to use the [pop function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) then the correct syntax would be result.pop(0)

Comment: Thanks for the mention of the incorrect format of the pop function. Late and half a sleep. I changed from pop to index () so I can make use of the information later in my code. I now came across a new problem which I will start a new thread. Thanks for the support I am new to python and I am working along slowly and having fun solving issues as they come along. I